# Using Keras Masking Layer when observations in each batch have different numbers of missing values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am building an RNN using Keras for sequences that have varying lengths. I have padded the missing values for each sequence with a value of -99 (I did not use 0, since this is a meaningful value in my dataset). The model has been defined like this:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-99, input_shape=(n_lags, n_input_vars)),
    keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.LSTM(16),
    keras.layers.Dense(3)
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), batch_size=100)
```

The training set has been batched into chunks of 100 observations. Each batch may contain observations (sequences) with different lengths, for example:

---

*Sequence 1:* [0, 1, 3], [-99, -99, -99], [-99, -99, -99]

*Sequence 2:* [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 10], [-99, -99, -99]

....

*Sequence 100:* [8, 7, 4], [-99, -99, -99], [-99, -99, -99]

---

Does the Keras Masking layer allow for this situation where the sequence length is different for the observations in a batch? Or do I need to build batches that have the same missing input values for every observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the LSTM recognizes which timepoints in the sequence are to be ignored since it comprehends the information that the Masking layer provides, and furthermore each sequence (within a batch) can have a different number of valid timepoints as in your example.  Additional information is here:  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

@ad2004 is only partially correct in the sense that LSTM with return_sequence = True can propagate the mask correctly, however, the second LSTM layer (default return_sequence = False) will lose the mask. So the mask is actually never propagated to the output layer, and hence the loss will still include the padded data (but of course, the Masking layer turns -99 to 0, just the loss will still include the part of padded values). To validate this, we can simply print out the input_mask and output_mask of each layer, if it is None then it means there is no mask.

```
for i, l in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(f'layer {i}: {l}')
    print(f'has input mask: {l.input_mask}')
    print(f'has output mask: {l.output_mask}')


layer 0: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Masking object at 0x6675b2f98>
has input mask: None
has output mask: Tensor("masking_7/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 30), dtype=bool)
layer 1: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent_v2.LSTM object at 0x66537f278>
has input mask: Tensor("masking_7/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 30), dtype=bool)
has output mask: Tensor("masking_7/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 30), dtype=bool)
layer 2: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent_v2.LSTM object at 0x6676b4588>
has input mask: Tensor("masking_7/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 30), dtype=bool)
has output mask: None
layer 3: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x6676b6240>
has input mask: None
has output mask: None
```

Comment: Not setting `return_sequences=True` in the last `LSTM` layer is very common, so do you know if there's a way to propagate the mask through to the end? Is that even necessary (i.e. how much will the loss be affected as is)?